# React is compiled with no errors but no component is displayed on browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, react-redux

I am new to React.

I have Installed React using `npm install create-react-app` .
I have created a `server.js` file, and my file structure is here.

[image]

> package.json

```
{
      "name": "my-app",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.17.1",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
        "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
        "classnames": "^2.2.5",
        "express": "latest",
        "lodash": "latest",
        "morgan": "^1.9.0",
        "prop-types": "latest",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
        "react-router": "^4.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
        "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
        "validator": "^9.2.0",
        "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.21.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "latest"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon --watch server --exec babel-node -- server.js",
        "start-dev": "node server.js",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
        "nstall": "^0.2.0",
        "react-hot-loader": "^3.1.3",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
        "redux": "^3.7.2",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
        "webpack": "^3.10.0",
        "webpack-dev-middleware": "^2.0.3"
      }
    }
```

> server.js File

```
import path from "path";

import express from 'express';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';
import webpackConfig from './webpack.config.dev';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

import users from './src/Actions/users';

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api/users',users);

const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

app.use(webpackMiddleware(compiler, {
    hot:true,
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
    noInfo: true
}));
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('*',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'./public/index.html'));
});
app.listen(5001, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 5001!'));
```

> Webpack.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devtool:'eval-source-map',

    entry: [
        'webpack-hot-middleware/',
        path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js')
    ],

    output:{
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
    ],
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        inline: false,
        contentBase: "./"
    },
    module:{
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loaders: [
                'react-hot-loader/webpack',
                'babel-loader?' +
                'babelrc=false,' +
                'presets[]=es2015,' +
                'presets[]=react'
            ]
        }]
    },
    resolve:{
        extensions:['.js']
    }
}
```

On running `npm run start` . It listens to the sufficient port and it compiles everything with no errors. But, On Browser it displays no components of React. It just Runs and does nothing.

> src/index.js File

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter, Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import App from './App';
import Greet from './Greetings';
import SignupPage from './signup/signup';

const stores = createStore(
    (state = {}) => state,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

ReactDOM.render((
    <Provider store={stores}>
    <BrowserRouter >
        <div>
            <Route component={App}>
            </Route>
            <div id={'jumbo'} className='container css'>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Greet}/>
                <Route path='/signup' component={SignupPage}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
), document.getElementById('app'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

How can I clear my code. I did not know where i did mistakes. Help me !!
Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: console showing no errors !!

Comment: I will try to add my app in git and I'l leave a link

Comment: You should open the developer tools in your browser (I recommend Chrome) and take a look at what happens on the browser side.

Comment: I have checked with opera browser with React developer tools extension to check what happens with react. It says nothing is connected to react.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused with what `create-react-app` does and how it works. From [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) docs:

> You don’t need to install or configure tools like Webpack or Babel.
>   They are preconfigured and hidden so that you can focus on the code.
>
> Just create a project, and you’re good to go.

Under the hood it builds your project with webpack.
So if you want to modify/add webpack you should look at `npm run eject` command.

> Running npm run eject copies all the configuration files and the transitive dependencies (Webpack, Babel, ESLint, etc) right into your project so you have full control over them. Commands like npm start and npm run build will still work, but they will point to the copied scripts so you can tweak them. At this point, you’re on your own.

So seems like you dont need your own `webpack.config.js` file. Moreover if you would like to have the webpack development server proxy your API requests to your API server you can add the next: `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001/"` into your `package.json` file to allow `webpack-dev-server` redirect your requests to your server.

Hope it make sence

Comment: Yes, **thank you very much**. I have gone in a wrong way. I have watched a old tutorial on YouTube. You get me right I am confused with `create-react-app`.  I will learn better. Good Day !!